# How To Reset Image In Form

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have 2 Images, `OriginalImage` and `TempImage`.

I use this code to load Image in form:

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
Temp= new Bitmap(2, 2);
Original = new Bitmap(2, 2);
Original=Temp;
```

and change the Temp image(Rotate,Crop,etc)

When reset, I load the Original Image to load Elementary image in form but load the Temp image.

Comment: I don't have a C# compiler here, but I think you need to copy `Temp` to `Original` by way of a `Clone` method or the like, not with `=`. `=` is too shallow, so they end up being simply the same object, not copies of one another.

Comment: Well done. What's your question?

Comment: Your one bitmap is lost, and other one is refered by 2 variables. It is dangerous. If you dispose one, other one will break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `Bitmap` is a class, and when you say `Original = Temp`, you're telling `Original` to reference the same `Bitmap` instance as `Temp`.

The `Bitmap` that you instantiated for `Original` is lost and will be garbage collected, and if you dispose either one, both will stop working.

What you're looking for in that last line is [`Bitmap.Clone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.clone.aspx), so that you create a copy of Temp and store that in Original:

```
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    Temp= new Bitmap(2, 2);
    Original = (Bitmap)Temp.Clone();
```

Comment: Original = (Bitmap)(Temp.Clone())